# Android Json Parsing From postman URL

Tags: json, parsing, android-studio

i'm a beginner with json , 
and I can't find any tutorial that shows json parsing from url and show it in a list view ,

i want to parse this json from url like it's showing below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);

 // Getting JSON Array node
 JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

// looping through All Data
   for (int i = 0; i <data.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

    String id = c.getString("id");
    String name = c.getString("name");
    String email = c.getString("ordering");
    String address = c.getString("images");

}

catch(Exception e)
{
  //Json exception here
}
```